# Вывод названия страницы таксономии записей WP

Tags: php, wordpress

создал каталог товаров на wordpress через Toolset добавил новый тип записи "товары" и к ним семантику "категории товаров"

на каждой странице у меня после шапки есть блок где выводится заголовок страницы the_title(), допустим на странице "контакты" это будет "контакты", на странице новости соответственно "Новости" а на странице категории товаров название категории соответственно.

я сделал этот блок в header.php свой темы ведь он подключается на все страницы

вывод сделал так

```
 echo single_cat_title('',0) != '' ? single_cat_title() : the_title();
```

это работает везде кроме страницы /product/ - эта страница на которой выводятся все записи типа "товар" - по какой то причине вместо слова "товары" the_title() там выводит название последнего добавленного в каталог товара

подскажите как это сделать правильно
я вже пробовал делать это так

```
 if (is_page('contacts')) { echo 'Контакты'; } 
else if (is_page('about')) { echo 'О компании'; } 
 else if (is_page('servis')) { echo 'Услуги'; } 
else if (is_page('product')) { echo 'Товары'; } 
else { echo single_cat_title('',0) != '' ? single_cat_title() : the_title(); }
```

оно всё равно выводит мне в общем каталоге товаров (не в отдельной категории вроде /product-cat/generatori/ там все отлично выводит мне допустим "генераторы") название последнего добавленного товара

какую функцию посоветуете использовать для данной цели? ведь вывод "хлебных крошек" через bcn_display();  без труда распознает страницу на которой я нахожусь и выдает все правильно "Главная -> Товары"

Answer (score 1):

Страницы, посты и произвольные типы постов - это сущность `WP_Post`. Категории, теги и различные таксономии это сущность `WP_Term`.

Для вывода заголовка для сущности `WP_Post` используйте функцию `the_title()`, а для сущности `WP_Term` - `single_term_title()`.

Пример кода:

```
is_singular() ? the_title() : single_term_title();
```

Comment: спасибо это от части помогло но теперь на странице /product/ не выводит имя послезнего товара, но и слово "товары" тоже почему то не выводит - не показывает ничего(

Comment: Что за страница /product/? Какое отношение имеет тут последний товар?)

Comment: продукт просто я сделал новый вид записей сделанный в toolset и соответственно страница для него archive-product.php и для самой позиции single-product.php ну а в адресной строке она как раз /product/